# mediumtext / longtext - Entity Framework code first migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've using Entity Framework Code First Migrations for my database, and in one of the latest tables that I've created for data, I'm storing JSON data, in rare cases up to 100,000 characters. The database we are using is MySQL, and `nvarchar(MAX)` doesn't exist, and the maximum length is capped around 20,000. I wanted to use either `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` to store this Json data but I can't find an appropriate attribute to add to the `string` property in the class to do this.

Stuff I've tried:-

- `[Column(TypeName = "text")]`
- `[Column(TypeName = "mediumtext")]`
- `[Column(TypeName = "MEXIUMTEXT")]`

What is interesting is that with these when the migration runs and the partial class is generated if I change either of the following:-

`AlterColumn("dbo.ApiAiItems", "JsonData", c => c.String(unicode: false, storeType: "text"));`

or...

`AlterColumn("dbo.ApiAiItems", "JsonData", c => c.String(unicode: false));`

to...

`AlterColumn("dbo.ApiAiItems", "JsonData", c => c.String(unicode: false, storeType: "mediumtext"));`

The correct datatype gets set on the MySQL database table. So the issue is getting the migration to generate the correct type.

Could anyone suggest anything? Or is editing that partial .CS file acceptable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You did not indicate what version of Entity Framework you are using, but I do something similar to the following in my OnModelCreating method to apply SQL Server data types based upon entity property reflection.  Something similar may work for you.  I do not have ready access to a MySQL instance to test, so your mileage may vary.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().Any(a => a.TypeName.ToLowerInvariant() == "mediumtext"))
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("mediumtext"));

        modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().Any(a => a.TypeName.ToLowerInvariant() == "longtext"))
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("longtext"));
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Did the code get you closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: I've been working away from this code since then. I'll update next week, as I will work on it again. I suspect it's exactly what I am looking for, having seen another dev do this at work for another reason.